# pthreads : What are the different models of pthread implemenation

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I read all about pthread and its related APIs to create, lock and synchronize different threads. But I often find word hints like threadpool, consumer/producer etc. I understand that these are models of pthread implementation.

Can anyone please let me know the various models of pthread implementation with its advantages / disadvantages if any over each other? What type of scenario we should use which model?

Also why some C system library functions are not safe to be called in threads routines like - strtok etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.cs.uml.edu/~fredm/courses/91.308-fall05/files/pthreads.pdf

Comment: Some patterns related to multithreading are listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't models of pthread implementation. thread pools and consumer/producer are things you can implement using pthreads.

How pthreads is implemented depends on the operating system you are using. pthreads is basically an API.

Some C functions aren't re-entrant, because they were written before threading was a consideration, so it's not a good idea to call them in a threaded program. strtok for instance stores where it last got to in your string (so it's not a good idea to call strtok on 2 different strings at the same time, let alone in a threaded context).

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please let me know what are the standard implementation practice of pthread with a brief concept?

Comment: there is no standard implementation. it normally devolves into calls into the operating system. Try googling 'pthread concepts'